# Python TypeHint for Pathlib with Structural Typing (PEP 544)

Tags: python, type-hinting

I have a project where a type hint for PosixPath (pathlib) would be very helpful. I think this should be doable using Structural Typing something like this -

```
# Python 3.8.5
from typing import Protocol
from pathlib import Path, PosixPath

class SupportsPosixPath(Protocol):
    def obj(self) -> PosixPath:
         ...

_home: SupportsPosixPath = Path("~")
_application_dir: SupportsPosixPath = Path("application")
_data_dir: SupportsPosixPath = Path("data")

def do_path_stuff(_home, _application_dir, _data_dir) -> SupportsPosixPath:
     _complete_path = _home.joinpath(_application_dir)
     _complete_path = _complete_path.joinpath(_data_dir)
     _complete_path = _complete_path.expanduser()
     _complete_path = (
     _complete_path.ascii_lowercase()
     )  # This should raise a linter error because PosixPath doesn't support ascii_lowercase.
     return _complete_path
```

The PyCharm linter doesn't raise any errors/issues. When I run `mypy` against ^^^ I get -

```
$ mypy foo.py 
foo.py:11: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Path", variable has type "SupportsPosixPath")
foo.py:12: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Path", variable has type "SupportsPosixPath")
foo.py:13: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Path", variable has type "SupportsPosixPath")
```

If I change the typehint to 'Path' (below) I don't get any errors via `mypy` or the PyCharm linter but I should because 'Path' doesn't support `.ascii_lowercase` -

```
# Python 3.8.5
from typing import Protocol
from pathlib import Path  # , PosixPath


# class SupportsPosixPath(Protocol):
    # def obj(self) -> PosixPath:
        # ...


_home: Path = Path("~")
_application_dir: Path = Path("application")
_data_dir: Path = Path("data")


def do_path_stuff(_home, _application_dir, _data_dir) -> Path:
    _complete_path = _home.joinpath(_application_dir)
    _complete_path = _complete_path.joinpath(_data_dir)
    _complete_path = _complete_path.expanduser()
    _complete_path = (
        _complete_path.ascii_lowercase()
    )  # This should raise a linter error because PosixPath doesn't support ascii_lowercase.
    return _complete_path
```

Running `mypy` on ^^^ -

```
$ mypy foo.py 
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Comment: Can you expand on 'doesn't have any impact'. Do you mean mypy or PyCharm's linter?

Comment: @henrycjc I've updated my question with mypy's behavior. It's different than PyCharm's linter but still not right.

Comment: Your function's `_home` argument has no relation to the `_home` global variable. You have not type hinted any of your function's arguments.

Comment: (You also haven't type hinted `_complete_path`.)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica That was it, thanks! I had assumed that the type hint I used when I set the initial variables would be inherited when I used them.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @user2357112_supports_Monica in the comments. I didn't need to create my own type, I needed to move my type hints to the function. The code below works with the mypi and PyCharm linters -

```
# Python 3.8.5
from pathlib import Path


_home = Path("~")
_application_dir = Path("application")
_data_dir = Path("data")


def do_path_stuff(_home, _application_dir, _data_dir) -> Path:
    _complete_path: Path = _home.joinpath(_application_dir)
    _complete_path: Path = _complete_path.joinpath(_data_dir)
    _complete_path: Path = _complete_path.expanduser()
    return _complete_path


p = do_path_stuff(_home, _application_dir, _data_dir)
print(p)
```